# Slow query execution for select query using MemSql for c# application

Tags: c#, singlestore

I have installed MemSql over Linux machine, I have one c# application which i run over windows machine, where i am making connection with MemSql database and hitting simple select query. But query execution using c# application takes around 3-4 seconds. Same select query if i try to run in console of MemSql take 400-500 ms. please refer screenshot here. [memSql console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCjxL.png)
I am not able to understand why it is taking much time when i run c# application, please help me out to improve query performance using c# for this.

Initially I have installed MemSql over windows machine, i thought may be docker can make issue. Because to run Memsql need to start Docker service.
After that, i have installed MemSql over Linux machine and tried again. But there is not much difference in result.

C# code is as below:-

```
MySqlConnection conn= new MySqlConnection();

conn.ConnectionString = "Server=servername;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd =;Port=3306; protocol=socket; pooling=true; minpoolsize=10;maxpoolsize=500;";
conn.Open();

string query = "SELECT * from POLICY_HEADER_HISTORY";
var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

conn.Close();
```

i would require output with-in milliseconds same as Memsql console, because it is simple select query which i tried to run.

Comment: How many records are being returned?  Your query is selecting and returning the whole table !  Some SQL editors automatically add a LIMIT 10 to every SELECT.

Comment: Yeah, I second that question. It is pretty common for large numbers of rows to take a long time to process on the client side.

Comment: there are around 300 records returned. that is not big number. 
I have tried to select only two columns but response time is around 2 seconds, not big difference. It is just select query which returns only 300 records, same query in MemSql editor take 400-500 ms. how can i improve this?

Comment: Are you timing the first query execution only? Connection overhead/code generation/other startup costs are not uncommon. How much time does the *second* execution take?

Comment: For 1st, it takes around 3.39 seconds, when i try to run 2nd,3rd time etc only milliseconds difference not much compare to first.

Comment: How  are you timing the console one? are you including login?

Comment: here console is MemSql's Sql editor, where i run query and query execution time i have majored.

Comment: MemSql is installed over linux server, but access this console over windows server.

Comment: Please put the exact column types in your question. Don't describe them in general terms. Exact column names, exact column types please.

Comment: `MemSql is installed over linux server, but access this console over windows server.` Please show us a screenshot of this console, since I am still unclear where exactly it is running.

Comment: If by console you mean in that web browser, it is likely running on or close to the database server. It may be running faster simply due to lower network latency.

Comment: I have attached screenshot for memsql in Question, Please have a look into it. i.e. Memsql editor which i have used to run query. Another side, i have created one c# application, which is executing same select query but execution time is differ, how i can improve in my c# application?

Comment: If you compile the C# code, using .NET Core, and run it on the same web server that runs https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCjxL.png - how long does it take then? Also, please show the column types as requested.

Comment: Can you measure how long does just running `select 1` take? Could it be a slow network connection from your Windows machine to the database?